# Plotting two different dataframes with different sizes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am having issue plotting two dataframs. One has 20711 entries, the other is 20710 entries. I am using plot(x,y) to plot like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig1 = plt.figure(figsize= (10,10))
ax = fig1.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(X, Y)
```

Both are dataframes that were pulled from a csv. that have this structure:

```
print(X)
0        -2.343060
1        -2.445431
2        -2.335754
3        -2.478535
4        -2.527026
print(Y)
0        0.026940
1       -0.075431
2        0.024246
3       -0.118535
4       -0.167026
5       -0.145475
```

I keep getting error:

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
```

How do I fix it so that it ignores the last entry?

Comment: Since there is no difference between having 20711 and 20710 entries and having 4 and 5 entries, you can easily create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks I edited the comment with both x and y.

Comment: What I mean with a minimal example is something that I can copy+paste, run, obtain the error, do some corrections and paste back here. I'm not very motivated at writing the complete code myself just for a short error-correction. If you can't spend 10 minutes on writing an MCVE, why should I spend even 5 Minutes on it?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Ah I see what you mean by this. Thanks for the input sorry I am new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you can just ditch the last value of Y then the following should work, assuming you have the index in your dataframe too, that is, your csv looks like this:

```
0,-2.343060
1,-2.445431
2,-2.335754
3,-2.478535
4,-2.527026
```

and you loaded it like `X=pandas.read_csv('x.csv')`, then

```
ax.plot(X.as_matrix().T[1], Y.as_matrix().T[1][:-1])
```

should work.

As you mentioned in your comment the overlap varies:

```
ax.plot(X.as_matrix().T[1], Y.as_matrix().T[1][:len(x)])
```

Comment: Ah yeah, I think I should have mentioned that it can vary between data set that I am using. So I am looking for away to have plot(x,y) to ignore any extra data that is passed to it.

Comment: I added it to my answer, this assumes len(y)>len(x) though, otherwise, you'd have to check for that first.

Comment: Huh, would plotting in panda be easier then? would it take care of all this stuff? The reason I am asking is because I have so many different data set with varying x and y. I am wondering if going to panda would make my life easier.

Comment: I have always plotted stuff in matplotlib, you could try it, but I don't know how to do it...